# iOS - Is possible to combine Swift 3 and Swift 4 code within one project?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, xcode9

I have a project (Xcode 9) that uses a lots of 3rd party libraries. Some of them are written in Swift 3 (only) and some other in Swift 4 (only).

There is an option in `Build Settings > Swift` that allows to choose version 3 **or** version 4, so only "one half" of the code is valid.

**Is there a way how to use both versions in one project?**

**Or is there some "automatic code converter" that is able to translate Swift 3 code to Swift 4 standards?**

Comment: are you using cocoa pods, or do you add those libraries manually?

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ manually.

Comment: very little has changed between swift 3 and swift 4. You shouldn't have to do much at all to "translate" your pods to swift 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using CocoaPods to manage your 3rd party dependencies then yes you can. The Swift version can be set in the Build Settings for the pod target in the pod project.

So you can have an app running Swift 4 that uses libraries built for Swift 3.2 fine.

If you're adding the 3rd party libs to your main project then it might not be possible, although you could extract the libs into their own projects (or private cocoapods) and add to your workspace and set the Swift version on each individually

And Xcode should have a warning prompting you to convert to Swift 4 which you can click, which *should* convert your project to Swift 4 automatically but you may end up having to fix some warnings/errors manually

Comment: As far as I know, very little has changed (syntax-wise) between Swift 3 and Swift 4. I simultaneously use both versions in all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your swift 3 code to swift 4 and your code will work as expected.

Xcode may suggest you to conververt code to swift 4.